# Cygwin top command - See processes for all users

Tags: cygwin

Does anybody know how to see the processes for all users using `top` command in Cygwin (part of `procps` library under System).

I know this can be done in *nix but I am struggling in Cygwin. I have tried using `pslist` but it does not behave in a putty SSH console.

I need to have a solution where I can see a `top` like dialog using SSH. I do not have any NTLM SSO access to the Win2k3 guest at all so ssh is the only way in.

Comment: After many years of working with Cygwin off and on, I have swayed towards using ProcessExplorer and Windows 7+ built in Resource Monitor. I really like both and but have found that Process Monitor is an excellent tool for inspecting processes that are very heavily hitting the file I/O.

Comment: How do you use `PROCEXP.EXE` or `PROCMON.EXE` over `ssh`? Do they have a terminal mode?

Answer (score 35):

`top` only displays Cygwin processes. `ps -W` will list Windows processes as well.

Comment: The following link shows one way: http://superuser.com/questions/751688/is-there-a-way-to-show-windows-processes-in-cygwin-constantly/887564#887564

Answer (score 3):

Manytimes the command "tasklist" gets the job done more effectively. It built into windows, just make sure your System32 folder is part of your bash profile PATH. There is also procps itself. You should also try using mintty for your terminal. You could always try attaching any of these task apps to screen, and or using watch to poll the information.

Comment: Thanks. `TASKLIST /FO CSV /NH` gives you process CPU time (since start) with second granularity in a parseable way, so one could run that twice with a 100 second interval to have a rough idea of biggest long-running CPU usage processes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can do something like:

```
wmic process get ProcessId,Name,UserModeTime,KernelModeTime /EVERY:1
```

The User and Kernel mode times there seem to be expressed in 1/10,000,000th of second.

You should be able to post-process that output to get the CPU-usage per second.

Here using cygwin's `perl`:

```
wmic process get ProcessId,Name,UserModeTime,KernelModeTime /EVERY:1 |
  perl -lne '
    if (/\S/) {
      my ($k,$c,$p,$u) = split /\s{2,}/;
      $n{"$p\t$c"}=$k+$u;
    } else {
      my %c;
      for my $k (keys %n) {
        $c{$k} = $n{$k} - $o{$k} if defined $o{$k}
      }
      print "$_\t" . $c{$_}/1e5 for (sort {$c{$b}<=>$c{$a}} keys %c)[0..20];
      %o = %n; %n = undef; print ""
    }'
```

Outputs something like:

```
0       System Idle Process     588.12377
2196    sh.exe  107.00075
248     svchost.exe     85.80055
7140    explorer.exe    26.52017
[...]
```

every second.

Note that if the *System Idle Process* shows just under 800% on an idle system, that's because your system has 8 CPU cores (well at least 8 threads) as that counts the CPU time of all CPUs.

Also note that the `EVERY:1` above is a lie. `wmic` doesn't seem to give that output every second. More likely, it sleeps roughly 1 second between each report and doesn't compensate for the time it takes to compute the report. So in practice, it will run every 1 second and a bit which means those percentages are not very accurate and slightly overestimated.